# Cannot get my routes that have been defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I am trying to add routes to my expressjs project. I am trying to make it so that when I go to 'localhost:9000/users' it returns 'User List'. Currently it shows ,'Cannot GET /users'. I have tried putting the code in users.js into server.js and replaced the router with app but that did not work.
routes/users.js:

```
const express = require("express")
const router = express.Router()

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("User List")
})

router.get("/new", (req, res) => {
  res.render("users/new")
})

module.exports = router;
```

server.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 9000
const userRouter = require("routes/users")
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', {username: 'xpress'})
})

app.use("/users", userRouter)

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App listening at port ${port}`)
})
```

Comment: Try `res.status(200).send({data: "User List"})` in routes/users.js
Also, in server.js, ensure you are returning json data by adding `app.use(express.json())` before app.set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copy your code and only modify

`const userRouter = require("routes/users")`

to

`const userRouter = require("./routes/users")`

and I have the desired output

[image]

You should use `"./"` to refer to your files. Otherwise, Node.js will search for package "routes/users" in built-in packages, globally-installed packages, and in `node_modules` folder. Of course, it doesn't available in these places.